# How to bulk optimize images using Mozjpeg on ubuntu server?

Tags: ubuntu, nginx, ubuntu-16.04, mozjpeg

I want to optimize images bulk and i read mozjpeg`s usage , there no have how to work bulk on server.

Could you tell me how to optimize that?

Thank you.

Comment: This is very unclear. Also, does this have anything to do with programming?

Answer (score 3):

Tested on Ubuntu 16.04 to batch or bulk optimize all jpegs recursively given any folder using mozjpeg pre-compiled binaries.   Execute the following commands:

First download and install mozjpeg...
For 64bit:

```
wget https://mozjpeg.codelove.de/bin/mozjpeg_3.2_amd64.deb
dpkg -i mozjpeg_3.2_amd64.deb
```

For 32bit:

```
wget https://mozjpeg.codelove.de/bin/mozjpeg_3.2_i386.deb
dpkg -i mozjpeg_3.2_i386.deb
```

Then link mozjpeg's jpegtran...

```
ln -s /opt/mozjpeg/bin/jpegtran /usr/bin/jpegtran
```

Then download this perl script which will recursively scan for jpegs, optimize with the new jpegtran, and print results.

```
wget https://gist.githubusercontent.com/aksuited/96ea6144d9b62befbce23fd62b3b7b4d/raw/e31a74da9d7eaa6004969716f49c08e8d0a4de62/optimize_jpegs.pl
```

give the script permissions...

```
chmod 755 optimize_jpegs.pl
```

execute script...

```
optimize_jpegs.pl /path/to/jpegs
```

Sample Output:

```
# ./optimize_jpegs.pl /
Inspecting //2.2.jpg
 -- Huffman table optimization: saved 15681 bytes (orig 93901)
Inspecting //28ga 500ft 4oz 1.jpg
 -- Huffman table optimization: saved 3055 bytes (orig 25897)
Inspecting //104.jpg
 -- Huffman table optimization: saved 9566 bytes (orig 48080)
Inspecting /usr/share/doc/nodejs/full-white-stripe.jpg
Inspecting /usr/share/doc/nodejs/thin-white-stripe.jpg


----------------------------
  Sumary
----------------------------

  Inspected 5 JPEG files.
  Modified 3 files.
  Huffman table optimizations: 3
  Progressive JPEG optimizations: 0
  Total bytes saved: 28302 (orig 167878, saved 16.85%)
```

Comment: It works on 18.04 as well but I only get 7.9% rate... Also nothing for Progressive optimization. When I optimize some images with an online tool I get a rate like 70%